# Oracle Apex IG modify Action Menu

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to hide some specific features from IG's Action Menu.

I know how to to do it for example for highlight and stretch option

```
function(config){
     apex.util.getNestedObject(config, "views.grid.features").highlight = false;
     apex.util.getNestedObject(config, "views.grid.features").stretchColumns = false;
                    
    return config;
}
```

I can't find list of all features in that Menu. I want to keep only "Filtter", "Download" and "Help". Rest shouldn't be available.

And also how to hide column features with that configuration (I must do it here becouse it will be dynamic, depending on item). I want to keep only filter feature on columns.

Answer (score 0):

When the page has been loaded, run `apex.region("regionStaticId").call("option","config")` in Browsers Developer Tools, to get the config object.

Now you can view and navigate through all options that has been currently set for the current Interactive Grid. This should give you an overview of all the other options you want to differentiate from.

The options you already found, views.grid.features.highlight and views.grid.features.strechColumns, are also in there.

For more information, see https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet

There are lots of examples and links to other blogs, on how to customize your Interactive Grid. Including the must read to John Snyders (member of the APEX Team) blog series about the Interactive Grid.